# Line Spacing in BI Publisher

Tags: bi-publisher

I need to give 1.5 Spacing between two lines in a Paragraph. But I can't see any options like that.

I tried to copy the contents from MS Word with 1.5 line spacing, but once the report is saved, it looks like No spacing.

Answer (score 3):

This should be the standard spacing option in MS Word. Select the lines, on the 'Home' Tab, select the the arrow under Paragraph. You can select 1.5 lines under the spacing field in that dialog box.